# HTTP Post 400 (Bad Request) After DropDownList

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, knockout.js

My program is basically for technicians to key in their service report after they've fixed a computer.

I have one feature that allows them to create a new report and a part of the report is keying in the customer's name or in other words, the company's name.

I was first struggling to make a dropdownlist so that the technicians get easily pick the name of a customer that is already in the server. I gave up for a while and decided to put a normal

```
<input type="text"/>
```

and when I did a post method, everything worked fine.

However, after having succeeded at making a dropdownlist for the customers' names, I could not do a POST method any more due to a POST 400 (Bad Request). I checked the developer tools and noticed that instead of the name of the customer, it just inserted 'Object'.

My question is, will someone please point me in the right direction? I've been scratching my head the whole morning and I just can't figure out why.

**CreateReport.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Add New Report</h1>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Create New Report</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: addReport">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputCustName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer's Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <select data-bind="options:customers, optionsText: 'Name', value: newReport.CustomerName"></select>
                            <span data-bind="value"
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" data-bind="with: newReport">

                        <label for="inputRepId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Report Id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRepId" data-bind="value:Id" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDate" data-bind="value:Date" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputWarranty" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Warranty</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="radio" name="Warranty" value="true" data-bind="checked:Warranty">Yes
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="Warranty" value="false" data-bind="checked:   Warranty">No
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputNature" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nature of Service</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="radio" name="ServiceNature" value="Installation" data-bind="checked:ServiceNature">Installation <input type="radio" name="ServiceNature" value="Repair" data-bind="checked:ServiceNature">Repair
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="ServiceNature" value="Terminate" data-bind="checked:ServiceNature">Terminate <input type="radio" name="ServiceNature" value="Maintenance" data-bind="checked:ServiceNature">Maintenance
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputLabCost" class="col-sm-2 control-label">labour Charge</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputLabCost" data-bind="value:LabourCharge" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputMatCost" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Material Cost</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputMatCost" data-bind="value:TotalMaterial" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputTransport" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Transport</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputTransport" data-bind="value:Transport" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputTotal" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputTotal" data-bind="value:Total" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputComments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comments</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputComments" data-bind="value:Comments" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputCusId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer's ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCusId" data-bind="value:CustomerId" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <label for="inputEngId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Engineer's ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEngId" data-bind="value:UserId" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <!--
                        <script>
                            function myFunction() {
                                var y = document.getElementById("inputMatCost").value;
                                var z = document.getElementById("inputTransport").value;
                                var x = +y + +z;
                                document.getElementById("inputTotal").value = x;
                            }
                        </script>
                            -->



                        <!-- <select id="CustomerDropDown"></select> -->


                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is using bootstrap modal component. This replace the simple native javascript alert as Selenium (Assignment 2) has problem detecting native javascript alert and therefore unable to do recording correctly
    It is a bit longer but it also looks more presentatble as you can further style it if you like-->
<<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="reportAlert">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>New Report Has Been Successfully Added!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Back To Reports</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**app.js**(script that the view is connected to)

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.reports = ko.observableArray();
    self.customers = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.detail = ko.observable();
    self.newReport = {
        Id: ko.observable(),
        CustomerName: ko.observable(),
        Date: ko.observable(),
        Warranty: ko.observable(),
        ServiceNature: ko.observable(),
        LabourCharge: ko.observable(),
        TotalMaterial: ko.observable(),
        Transport: ko.observable(),
        Total: ko.observable(),
        Comments: ko.observable(),
        CustomerId: ko.observable(),
        UserId: ko.observable()
    }

    var reportsUri = 'http://localhost:64744/api/report/';
    var customersUri = 'http://localhost:64744/api/customer/';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllReports() {
        ajaxHelper(reportsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.reports(data);
        });
    }

    function getCustomers() {
        ajaxHelper(customersUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.customers(data);
        });
    }

    self.getReportDetail = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper(reportsUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.detail(data);
        });
    }

    //GET method, addReport
    self.addReport = function (formElement) {
        var report = {
            Id: self.newReport.Id(),
            CustomerName: self.newReport.CustomerName(),
            Date: self.newReport.Date(),
            Warranty: self.newReport.Warranty(),
            ServiceNature: self.newReport.ServiceNature(),
            LabourCharge: self.newReport.LabourCharge(),
            TotalMaterial: self.newReport.TotalMaterial(),
            Transport: self.newReport.Transport(),
            Total: self.newReport.Total(),
            Comments: self.newReport.Comments(),
            CustomerId: self.newReport.CustomerId(),
            UserId: self.newReport.UserId()
        };

        ajaxHelper(reportsUri, 'POST', report).done(function (item) {
            self.reports.push(item);

            $('#reportAlert').modal('show');

        });
    }

    $('#reportAlert').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        window.location = "ReportInfo";
    })

    //DELETE METHOD deleteReportMethod
    self.deleteReport = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper(reportsUri + item.Id, 'DELETE').done(function (data) {
            //just to inform the user that delete has been performed
            $('#deleteRepAlert').modal('show');
        });
    }
    // jquery event to detect when the user dismiss the modal.... to redirect back to the home page
    $('#deleteRepAlert').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        window.location = "ReportInfo";
    })

    // Fetch the initial data.
    getAllReports();
    getCustomers();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling Knockout what property holds the value to be stored in the `options` binding. I am guessing that the `customers` array holds complex objects. So you need to tell Knockout which property on those objects holds the value. If you want to store the Name property as the value as well:

`<select data-bind="options:customers, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Name', value: newReport.CustomerName"></select>`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status 400 indicates that your parameter is wrong. Maybe parameter type or parameter name

Comment: The parameter is wrong. When I looked at the Developer Tools, instead of the customer's name being inserted, it was just 'Object'. The thing is, I have no idea why that is happening.